# SQL: Evitar repetir linha e soma valores

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql

Tenho esse select:

```
select 
  DISTINCT (clients.name) as nomeempresa, 
  payments.amount_paid as pagamento, 
  receipts.original_amount as recebimento
FROM 
  payments, 
  receipts, 
  receipt_status, 
  payment_status, 
  clients
WHERE 
  payments.id = payment_status.id AND
  receipts.id = receipt_status.id AND
  clients.id = payments.client_id AND
  clients.id = receipts.client_id AND
  payments.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND payments.created_at > CURRENT_DATE-1 OR 
  receipts.created_at < CURRENT_DATE AND receipts.created_at > CURRENT_DATE-1
 GROUP BY
  nomeempresa, pagamento, recebimento
```

Porém a saída:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho de filtrar a saida e mostrar o total na próxima coluna.

Comment: SUM( receipts.original_amount) e  remove receitas ele do group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui obter o resultado com uma linha de comando:

```
SUM( receipts.original_amount)
```

Resposta completa:

```
select 
  DISTINCT (clients.name) as nomeempresa, 
  SUM (payments.amount_paid) as pagamento, 
  SUM (receipts.original_amount)  as recebimento
```